# How to print numpy array in binary representation mode

Tags: python, numpy, binary

I have a following numpy array

> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4 ,11, 12,13,14,21,22,23,24,31,32,33,34 ]],
>   dtype=uint8)

when I print a i am getting the following output

```
[[ 1  2  3  4 11 12 13 14 21 22 23 24 31 32 33 34]]
```

**How can i get the output in binary representation?**

for example

```
[[ 00000001  00000010  00000011  00000100 ...]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
np.array(map(bin, a.flatten())).reshape(a.shape)
```

Comment: This is the fastest solution so far

Comment: This gives `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (1,16)` on Python 3 and numpy 1.21.5.

Comment: @MichaelHerrmann you may be interested in `np.unpackbits(a).reshape(*a.shape,8)`. The `8` is for uint8. Replace with the number of bits in your dtype.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [numpy.binary_repr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.binary_repr.html)

It takes a number as input and returns its binary representation as a string. You can vectorize this function so that it can take an array as input:

```
np.vectorize(np.binary_repr)(a, width=8)
```

Answer (score 2):

this gives out as u required

```
[bin(x)[2:].zfill(8) for x in a]
```

out put

```
['00000001', '00000010', '00000011']
```

Comment: This works perfectly.Thanks.. It is taking similar time to using vectorize.

Comment: pls make it tick .. and ote up:)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4 ,11, 12,13,14,21,22,23,24,31,32,33,34 ]], dtype=uint8)
print [bin(n) for n in a[0]]
```

Using numpy's `unpackbits`, this can work too.

```
A=np.unpackbits(a, axis=0).T
print [''.join(map(str,a)) for a in A]
```

Comment: Second one throws "TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration"

Comment: I think your array is not 2d. In your question you use two brackets `[[]]`.

Answer (score 1):

For uint8 you can use the builtin numpy function unpackbits. (As mentioned by @ysakamoto)
First reshape array so it is 1 column wide.
After that use unpackbits as stated below.

```
a = numpy.array([[1,2,3,4 ,11, 12,13,14,21,22,23,24,31,32,33,34 ]], dtype="uint8")
print(numpy.unpackbits(a.reshape(-1,1), axis=1))
```

output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```